# How can I display error code description in sample code section?

Tags: openapi, springdoc, redoc

I have an error code description displayed in the main section:
[image]

But I'd like also to display those code description in the example section here:

[image]

I saw some API docs that can generate those descriptions in the example section:

[image]

How can I do such a thing?

PS: Note that I am exposing open API specs with springdoc.

Comment: Have you tried the below answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what I want and It didn't work out. maybe because I am using redoc.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is you can define a string as an example in `@ApiResponse`

You can achieve this in two way

**1.** Define your error message format class or you can use build in if any

```
public class ExceptionResponse {

    private Instant time;
    private int status;
    private String error;
    private String exception;
    private String message;
}
```

Then define your custom message string as shown below.

```
public static final String exampleInternalError = "{\r\n" + "  \"status\": 500,\r\n" + "\"error\": Bad Request,\r\n"
            + "  \"message\": \"Your custome message goes here\"\r\n" + "}";
```

same is used to show the example as

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request", 
                  content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ExceptionResponse .class), 
                        examples = @ExampleObject(description = "Bad Request", value = exampleInternalError)))
```

This will show on swagger as
[image]

**2.** If you don't want to use in the above format then you can simply use

as mentioned below

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request", 
content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class), 
              examples = @ExampleObject(description = "Bad Request", value = "\"Your details about error code and error message goes here")))
```

This will show on swagger as
[image]